# making ssh hosts global to all the users on the computer

Tags: configuration, openssh

So **SSH** has these files that configure settings for a specific user.

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
~/.ssh/config
~/.ssh/id_rsa
~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

I'd like to globalise some of these files, like `config` and `known_hosts`. So that other users ( including **root** ) could share the configured hosts.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For `~/.ssh/config` you can place relevant system-wide settings in /etc/ssh/ssh_config according to [the man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5):

> ssh(1) obtains configuration data from the following sources in the following order:
>
> 1. command-line options
> 2. user's configuration file (~/.ssh/config)
> 3. system-wide configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config)
>
> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used.  The configuration files contain sections separated by “Host” specifications, and that section is only applied for hosts that match one of the patterns given in the specification.

Note that only the first value will be used, which means that the user can always override the system-wide configuration options locally.

For `~/.ssh/known_hosts` you can use `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` or another file specified by the GlobalKnownHostsFile configuration option:

> GlobalKnownHostsFile
>
> Specifies a file to use for the global host key database instead of /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts.

I'm unsure if it is possible for the other files, but I imagine you could work something out with symlinks if you *really* wanted to share private keys among users as well.

Comment: You've got a typo in your GlobalKnownHostsFile quote.

Comment: You can set UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ssh will never find a valid key inside users known_hosts file but still user can accept one temporary.

Comment: @Janning, it looks like there's actually an `IgnoreUserKnownHosts` option for that (values `yes` or `no`).

Comment: Note that the global `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` file must be world-readable. I was using `ssh-keygen -Hf /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` to rehash mine after manually adding entries, and it appears that it was being set to owner-only.

Answer (score 1):

Since root is all powerful, I would use a root cron job to copy the files form other users. Known Hosts and authorized keys can simply be appended. If it's all on one partitions there's the hardlink option. Not sure if symlinks would work for the files, but you could try that, too, you just have to put them in in a shared, yet secure place.

Comment: It would prevent users from adding their own hosts which IMHO is unintended effect.

Comment: I forget if a hardlink file has to have same perms but I suspect it does. However you could copy the file with cron and then make sure the perms are correct.